# How do I change the log level of a running process with log4rs?

Tags: logging, rust

I am trying to change log-level dynamically during the run of my Rust program.

I used log4rs as in [their example](https://github.com/estk/log4rs/blob/master/examples/log_to_file.rs#L47) they claimed it's possible.

But when I run the following program it crashes - when I try to change the log level - and I think it's a restriction of the log API (according to that: https://github.com/rust-lang/log/blob/master/src/lib.rs#L1278)

Is there anyway other way that I could change the log-level in runtime?

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
use log4rs::append::console::ConsoleAppender;
use log4rs::append::console::Target;
use log4rs::config::{Appender, Config, Root}; 

use log::*;

fn main() {
    let level_info = log::LevelFilter::Info; 
    let level_trace = log::LevelFilter::Trace;


    let stderr = ConsoleAppender::builder().target(Target::Stderr).build();
    let config = Config::builder().appender(
        Appender::builder()
            .build("stderr", Box::new(stderr)),
    ).build(
        Root::builder()
            .appender("stderr")
            .build(level_info),
    ).unwrap();

    log4rs::init_config(config).unwrap(); 


    error!("error"); //should print 
    warn!("warn");   //should print
    info!("info");   //should print
    debug!("debug"); //should  not print
    trace!("trace"); //should  not print 


    let stderr = ConsoleAppender::builder().target(Target::Stderr).build();
    let config = Config::builder().appender(
        Appender::builder()
            .build("stderr", Box::new(stderr)),
    ).build(
        Root::builder()
            .appender("stderr")
            .build(level_trace),
    ).unwrap();

    log4rs::init_config(config).unwrap(); 


    error!("error2"); //should print
    warn!("warn2");   //should print
    info!("info2");   //should print
    debug!("debug2"); //should print
    trace!("trace2"); //should print  

}
```

The output:

```
2020-04-20T12:07:53.351080400+01:00 ERROR use_log4rs - error
2020-04-20T12:07:53.354078400+01:00 WARN use_log4rs - warn
2020-04-20T12:07:53.356077200+01:00 INFO use_log4rs - info
thread 'main' panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err` value: SetLoggerError(())', src\main.rs:48:5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can only call `init_config` once. However, it returns a handle with a [`set_config`](https://docs.rs/log4rs/0.11.0/log4rs/struct.Handle.html#method.set_config) method, which you can call to change the configuration afterwards:

```
let hndl = log4rs::init_config(config).unwrap();

// ...
// Apply new config:
hndl.set_config(config);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b64dcb840d108e51ac82abcb70bd17c3)

Comment: Nice.  Kudos for the playground example.

Answer (score 2):

Jmb's answer is correct, but to change the log level of a process you don't need to change the config. `log4rs` relies on `log`, so you can just use `log::set_max_level`, which doesn't need a handle.

```rust
log::set_max_level(LevelFilter::Warn);
```

Just make sure you aren't filtering anything in the `log4rs` side.

[Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c6438f800a385269a6d798cc560a1534)