# Changing logging settings-- using fern-- in a Rust module, after logging has been initialized

Tags: logging, rust

I'm fairly new to rust, and I'm trying to implement logging with **fern**.  Setup is pretty straight-forward, and I'm successfully logging to a file and stdout.

I'd like to set the log level filter to Trace inside a module I'm debugging (and potentially make other, module-specific changes), but when I try to update the logging configuration inside the module, nothing seems to work.

I tried getting a new Dispatch inside the module so the config changes could be applied

```
    // Module: Problem Child
    ...
    fn trace_me() {
        let updated_logger = fern::Dispatch::new()
            .level(log::LevelFilter::Trace)
            .format(move |o, m, r| {o.finish(format_args!("[{l}] {m}", l = r.level(),))})
            .chain(fern::log_file("module.log")?)
            .apply()?;
        ...
    }

    fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        let original_logger = fern::Dispatch::new()
            .level(log::LevelFilter::Info)
            .format(move |o, m, r| {o.finish(format_args!("[{l}] {m}", l = r.level(),))})
            .chain(fern::log_file("main.log")?)
            .apply()?;
        let pita: ProblemChild = ProblemChild::new();
        pita.trace_me();
        ...
    }
```

but the new dispatch panics at .apply -- "Error: attempted to set a logger after the logging system was already initialized"

I tried to pass the original Dispatch to the function in the module to make the changes that way:

```
    // Module: Problem Child
    ...
    fn trace_me(bla: fern::Dispatch) {...}

    fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        let original_logger = fern::Dispatch::new()
            .level(log::LevelFilter::Info)
            .format(move |o, m, r| {o.finish(format_args!("[{l}] {m}", l = r.level(),))})
            .chain(fern::log_file("main.log")?)
            .apply()?;
        let pita: ProblemChild = ProblemChild::new();
        pita.trace_me(original_logger.clone());
        ...
    }
```

but Dispatch doesn't implement clone -- "error: no method named 'clone' found for struct 'Dispatch' in the current scope"

The documentation seems to suggest adding .into_shared() to the Dispatch might work,

```
    // Module: Problem Child
    ...
    fn trace_me(bla: fern::Dispatch) {...}

    fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        let original_logger = fern::Dispatch::new() 
            .into_shared()
        ...
        trace_me(original_logger.clone());
        ...
    }
```

but that returns a fern::builders::SharedDispatch which throws a type error -- "error: mismatched types.  label: expected struct 'Dispatch', found struct 'fern::builders::SharedDispatch'"

And modifying the function to take the SharedDispatch type fails as well:

```
    // Module: Problem Child
    fn trace_me(bla: fern::builders::SharedDispatch) {...}

    fn main() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
        let original_logger = fern::Dispatch::new() 
            .into_shared()
        ...
        trace_me(original_logger.clone());
        ...
    }
```

because builders is private -- "error: module 'builders' is private"

What am I missing?  Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: You may want to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75357406/edit) to make it more obvious that you're using [`fern`](https://crates.io/crates/fern) for logging. There are other options, and any solution depends on the logging crate.

Comment: For example, I don't know about `fern` but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61324604/5397009) gives a solution for [`log4rs`](https://crates.io/crates/log4rs).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Jmb! I edited the question to try to make it more clear that I'm using fern.  If no solutions are forthcoming, I'll take your suggestion and try switching to log4rs